# EF6 querying a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6 to call a stored procedure called `AlarmTransPro`. The procedure takes no input parameters as returns a table which has been declared within a model c# file in the project:

```
public partial class AlarmTransPro_Result
{
    public Nullable<int> id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> data1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> data1max { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> data1min { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Transitioned { get; set; }
}
```

I know the procedure logic and query works in isolation via its implementation in sqlfiddle: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7e149/5)

When I implement this method:

```
var alarmview = alarms.Database.SqlQuery<AlarmTransPro_Result>("AlarmTransPro").ToList();
```

and set a breakpoint when I mouse over I get a `Raw View` where `count=0`

If I try with the `.ToList()` i.e.

```
var alarmview = alarms.Database.SqlQuery<AlarmTransPro_Result>("AlarmTransPro")
```

then on mouse over I get `Non Public Members` and a `Results View`. The `Non Public Members` contains `Internal Query`and one of the sub fields is `sql parameters` and the has the string `object{0}`. The `Results View` states that

> Children could not be evaluated

I feel that I am close, but I am not sure if:

1. My query method is correct?
2. Do I need to include or make better provision in the query for the returned parameters?
3. Is it working and my method of inspection wrong?

Comment: are you sure that you are running the query against a database which contains data?

Comment: @dotctor - that is an interesting point. I have mapped the `stored procedures` as their own entity in the EF6 project. In this example `private sensorRepoEntities7 alarms = new sensorRepoEntities7();`. Could the problem be that I am running the query against the `stored procedures` and not the database?

Comment: no, connect to the exact database which ef connect and run the sp directly there and see the result.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not sure how to do this. Could you provide an example please?

Comment: try installing sql server management studio. and read some tutorials

Comment: I agree.  Install SSMS (Express is free) and run the stored procedure manually and look at the results.  Sometimes a debugging "Select" statement can throw off the results.